# Applying image transforms to remote images?

Tags: image-transforms

Is there any way to apply an image transform (either CP-defined or template-defined) to a variable which represents the URL of a remote image? Naturally it would need to be cached locally, but since transforms are already cached I figure it's not *too* much of a stretch.

My use case is applying a transform to the thumbnail image of a video which is being fetched by an oEmbed plugin.

Comment: ... crickets ...

Comment: Hi Derek, did you find a way to do it?

Comment: Nope, never got any action on this.

Answer (score 5):

[Imager](https://github.com/aelvan/Imager-Craft) plugin is capable of resizing remote images